# Character continues moving after sliding off a directional key

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am creating a platformer type game similar to Mario Brothers and I have come across a big problem. My problem is that when I tap on my directional key and drag out of it, the character keeps moving despite me having released the click. I already posted this question on the Corona Forums and I have not been able to come to a solution.

Here is my code:

```
local function makeControls(event)
if anim.isJumping == false then
  if event.phase == "began" then
    if event.target.isPressed == false then
      if event.target.id == "left" then
        walk(-1)
      elseif event.target.id == "right" then
        walk(1)
      end
    end
    event.target.isPressed = true
  elseif ( event.phase == "moved" and event.target.isPressed == true ) then
      if (
          event.x > event.target.contentBounds.xMin+4 and
          event.x < event.target.contentBounds.xMax-4 and
          event.y > event.target.contentBounds.yMin+4 and
          event.y < event.target.contentBounds.yMax-4
      ) then
          event.target:dispatchEvent( { name="touch", phase="began", target=event.target } )
        else
          event.target:dispatchEvent( {name = "touch", phase = "ended", target = event.target } )
      end
  elseif event.phase == "ended" then
    anim:setLinearVelocity(0,0)
    event.target.isPressed = false
  end
end
return true
end

  local function createArrowKey(group, x, y, rotation, name)
     local newButtonBoundary = display.newRoundedRect(group, x, y, 75, 75, 12)
     newButtonBoundary.strokeWidth = 6
     newButtonBoundary:setStrokeColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5)
     newButtonBoundary:setFillColor(1, 1, 1, 0.2)
     newButtonBoundary.id = name
     newButtonBoundary:addEventListener("touch", makeControls)
     newButtonBoundary.isPressed = false
     local newArrow = display.newPolygon(group, x, y, { 0, -24, 24, 24, -24, 24 })
     newArrow.rotation = rotation
     newArrow.strokeWidth = 3
  end

  createArrowKey(parent2, left + fullw / 3, bottom - fullh / 5.5, 90, "right")
  createArrowKey(parent2, left + fullw / 5.5, bottom - fullh / 5.5, 270, "left")
  createArrowKey(parent2, left + fullw / 3.88, bottom - fullh / 8.5, 180, "down")
  createArrowKey(parent2, left + fullw / 3.88, bottom - fullh / 3.9, 0, "up")
  createButton(parent2, left + fullw - 150, bottom - fullh / 5.5, "Shoot", "shoot")
  createButton(parent2, left + fullw - 250, bottom - fullh / 5.5, "Throw", "throw")
  createButton(parent2, left + fullw - 350, bottom - fullh / 5.5, "Melee", "melee")
```

Comment: Maybe try [joykey and vjoy by Ponywolf](https://github.com/ponywolf/joykey).

Comment: I have tried but I could never get the left and right movement to work.

Comment: Why doesn't the left and right movement work?

Comment: Because after I let go of the button with a sliding motion, the character will continue moving despite me having let go of the button.

Comment: So maybe something wrong is how you move character. You don't show `walk` function.

Answer (score 1):

I would try don't generate new events:

```
    local function makeControls(event)
if anim.isJumping == false then
  if event.phase == "began" then
    if event.target.isPressed == false then
      if event.target.id == "left" then
        walk(-1)
      elseif event.target.id == "right" then
        walk(1)
      end
    end
    event.target.isPressed = true
  elseif ( event.phase == "moved" and event.target.isPressed == true ) then
      if (
          event.x > event.target.contentBounds.xMin+4 and
          event.x < event.target.contentBounds.xMax-4 and
          event.y > event.target.contentBounds.yMin+4 and
          event.y < event.target.contentBounds.yMax-4
      ) then
          if event.target.id == "left" then
            walk(-1)
          elseif event.target.id == "right" then
            walk(1)
          end
        else
         anim:setLinearVelocity(0,0)
        event.target.isPressed = false
      end
  elseif event.phase == "ended" then
    anim:setLinearVelocity(0,0)
    event.target.isPressed = false
  end
end
return true
end
```

Comment: Same thing happens. By the way, this is Brent Sorrentino's code and he said he was working on a solution. (He put this up as a tutorial in Corona) Also, you're Polish?

Comment: Yeah, I'm Polish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Corona but maybe I can help you.

```
if event.phase == "began" then
    if event.target.isPressed == false then
      if event.target.id == "left" then
        walk(-1)
      elseif event.target.id == "right" then
        walk(1)
      end
    end
    event.target.isPressed = true
```

So if you touch the screen there will be a touch event with phase == "began".

Depending on which button you touched you will move left or right and you'll remember that that particular button is now pressed.

```
elseif ( event.phase == "moved" and event.target.isPressed == true ) then
      if (
          event.x > event.target.contentBounds.xMin+4 and
          event.x < event.target.contentBounds.xMax-4 and
          event.y > event.target.contentBounds.yMin+4 and
          event.y < event.target.contentBounds.yMax-4
      ) then
          event.target:dispatchEvent( { name="touch", phase="began", target=event.target } )
        else
          event.target:dispatchEvent( {name = "touch", phase = "began", target = event.target } )
      end
```

Now if your finger on that button and you move it there will be a touch evant with phase == "moved"  wich you handle in the lines above. If that move happens within your button ± 4 pixels around it you dispatch a touch event with phase == "began". So as long as you move within your button your guy will keep moving.

My question here: why do you do the same thing if your finger is in or outside the button? You will only enter the followin elseif block and hence stop moving if you lift your finger on the button. If you drag it off the button and lift it, the original touch event will never end and you don't create any other touch ended touch event.

```
elseif event.phase == "ended" then
    anim:setLinearVelocity(0,0)
    event.target.isPressed = false
  end
```

I believe you should dispatch a "touch" "ended" event in the else block, when your finger leaves the button.

This might fix your problem. Unfortunately I cannot test my proposed solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, when I add the ended phase in the else block, the same occurs. Also, I accidentally placed a previous version of the code where the else phase had a began phase dispatch.